# Locating an image with chrome dev tool

Tags: html, css

the little arrow in the image below is not align properly; for example in the image it is on the same row as "Fat Cat" but its really for "Dogs" I'm trying to fix this but I can't seem to locate where the little arrow is coming from. Normally I would right click and inspect the object and it would either display a link to an image or the css that generates it, however in this case I can't seem to find it. Any hints/tools? thanks!

[image]

I tried to inspect the element in chrome and looking through

Comment: can you provide an url to the page. I gues  that icon is a pseudo element (:before, :after)

Comment: @vnt brilliant. yes that is exactly what it was; I followed the ::before element to the css that was generating it.  thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the site. Try to check the `<li>` element (or the dogs container) for a `before` or `after` pseudo-element and inside the pseudo-element check the `content:''` attribute!